# How to execute and capture stdout of external command in Ruby using system() without shell escaping?

Tags: ruby, shell

I can call system("echo", "''"), and this won't be interpreted by a shell. I'll have expected result: '' on stdout. But I need to capture this output. %x is not an option, since I don't want to run shell, but execute command directly (and I don't want to do shell escaping).

Comment: You might like this gem [open4](http://github.com/ahoward/open4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IO::popen` ([API link](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002242))
[Slightly More In Depth Explanation](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_io.html#IO.popen)